# PHP math (numbering)

Tags: php, math

`$temp` is currently 6. But the variable result can be changing every time to a different number so it is not a fixed value.

Anyway, for this `$temp * 1.1666666`, the result will be `6.99999996`. Since I used the floor function, it will be rounded down to 6.

Is there any way when the value is more then`>*.49999` it will stay at `*.5` instead of `*`?

Example: `6.51111111`, `6.78948123`, `6.9747124`

**Expected Output:** 6.5

Example: `6.49999999`, `6.12412431`, `6.33452361`

**Expected Output:** 6

Do note that, $temp value will be ever changing..thank you!

Comment: Do you want to round to the nearest decimal point, or do you want to only increment by halves?

Comment: are you trying to do banker's rounding? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banker%27s_rounding#Round_half_to_even

Comment: Hi Jim, im not. The results of Round half to even is not what I need. I need +23.99 and below to stay as 23.5 23.49 and below to go to 23 :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code...

```
<?php 

    $temp = 6.94444;
    echo myRound($temp);

   function myRound($temp)
    {
        $frac = $temp - floor($temp);
        $frac = ($frac >= .5) ? .5 : 0;
        return ( floor($temp) + $frac );
    }

?>
```

Hope this is what you want.

Comment: Hi Ashwini. Unfortunately it does not work. When 1.166666 * 7 = 8.16666662. It gave out 7 as the answer..

Comment: You should check this one more time.
i have tried "echo myRound(1.166666 * 7);"
And m getting 8 as output.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`round($number, 1)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php). That will round to the nearest decimal point.

```
$number = round(.1666666 * $temp, 1);
```

If you want to round to the nearest half you can do this:

```
function round_to_half($num)
{
  if($num >= ($half = ($ceil = ceil($num))- 0.5) + 0.25) return $ceil;
  else if($num < $half - 0.25) return floor($num);
  else return $half;
}

$number = round_to_half(.1666666 * $temp);
```

Comment: Hey sorry tobyo, actually that's the wrong answer. I am  not looking for the nearest decimal point. I am actually looking forward to the answer i said above. Example: 6.3235235 Output: 6 Example: 6.50149235 Output: 6.5

Comment: Hi Conde, i tried. For the output of 5.9444444 it rounded up to 6 instead of 5.5